# What is wrong with my jquery fadein fadeout code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a code where when i click the button ('.click') it fadesout in replace of ('.name')

```
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="portfolio">Portfolio By</h1>
        <br> 
        <h1 class="click" > Click Me</h1>
        <h1 class="name">Eddie Weldon</h1>
    </div>

$('.click').click(function(){
    $('.click').fadeOut(3000).css({backgroundColor: rgba(59,207,119,.2)});
    $('.name').fadeIn();

    });
```

Comment: Your code currently will fade `.click` out at the same time as `.name` fading in. What's wrong with what's happening now? You want `.click` to fade out and then `.name` to fade in? Maybe you need to do `$('.click').fadeOut(3000,function() { $('.name').fadeIn(); }).css({backgroundColor: rgba(59,207,119,.2)});`? Describe what's happening now and what you expect to happen.

Comment: You fade it out first and then set the opacity to 0.2 - it's nothing but logical that it's still displayed.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Before I plug it in, I am expect that since the fadein name function is within the fadeout function , both effects will happen simultaneously.

Comment: Can you post your html and css too so I can see what you're seeing?

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: It worked thanks again Mike!

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your code and make it more readable by doing the following. This will allow you to cache your selectors, while binding your function to a click event.

```
;(function($){
var click = $('.click'),
    name = $('.name'),

clickHandler = function(){
 $(this).fadeOut(3000).css({background-color: 'rgba(59,207,119, 0.2)'});
 name.fadeIn();
};

click.on('click', clickHandler);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: so basically this variable makes it easier to follow the code and make it less confusing

Comment: It could make it easier to "follow" the code. But it caches the selector, which is a more efficient way to write your javascript.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.click').click(function(){
    $('.click').fadeOut(3000).css({"backgroundColor": "rgba(59,207,119,.2)"});
    $('.name').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.name{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="portfolio">Portfolio By</h1>
        <br> 
        <h1 class="click" > Click Me</h1>
        <h1 class="name">Eddie Weldon</h1>
    </div>
```